# Mac OSX fullscreen on multiple displays swiping moves all screens

Tags: macos, fullscreen, retina-display

This worked up until yesterday. 
Before and after updating to MacOS Sierra 10.12.5 did not solve problem.

## Config / Specs:

- Macbook pro OSX
- Dell monitor
- iPad using Duet app

### Previous functionality

I could expand fullscreen any app/program in Mac (the green button top right) and use 3 fingers on the trackpad to toggle between 'screens' on that individual physical screen.

## Current bug

When I fullscreen an app on one display and swipe with three fingers, swiping controls all 3 physical displays. The display in question swipes to the app, but the other two displays also swipe to the right showing blank black or white backgrounds and are mouseover-able.

## Desired functionality -- the Previous Functionality

Swiping on a screen only controls that display.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, there is a setting in Mission Control -> Displays have separate Spaces, checking this solves the problem for me.